# Why Android Toast is not showing?

Tags: android, toast

I've a problem on getting`Toast`

```
public class LiveMatch extends Fragment {

    private List<Items_list> matches;

    private static final String URL="https://www.cricbuzz.com/match-api/livematches.json";

    private String recent_match;


    View v;

    public LiveMatch() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.live, container, false);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        matches = new ArrayList<>();
        final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray live_match = new JSONArray(response);
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),live_match.length(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    for (int i = 0; i < live_match.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = live_match.getJSONObject(i);

                        recent_match = object.getString("mathes");

                        RecyclerView recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recycl);
                        RecylerAddapter recylerAddapter = new RecylerAddapter(getContext(), matches);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(recylerAddapter);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext())).add(stringRequest);
}
}
```

Comment: Try `getActivity()` instead of `v.getContext()`

Comment: @Suleyman still not getting

Comment: you are passing wrong `resId` in the params to  `makeText(Context context, 
                int resId, 
                int duration)` - `live_match.length()` is **NOT** a valid resource id

Comment: @ADM I've also use it but still not working

Comment: @pskink so how to do it ?

Comment: to do what? what actually do you want to achieve? you are trying to debug your code and you are not sure about how many elements is in `JSONArray live_match`? if so, then use `Log.d` method - this is a right way of doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is in Parsing JSON response.**

Web service(API) response comes in JSONObject and you are handling it in JSONArray.
See the response of [Livestream URL](https://www.cricbuzz.com/match-api/livematches.json)

[image]

Correct your code of handling response and it will work.

**Take note that you have to get values by iterating the loop using Iterator because matches object contains JSONObjects.**

Update your onResponse method as below:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        Log.e("Response: ", jsonObject.toString());
        JSONObject objMatch = jsonObject.optJSONObject("matches");
        Iterator<String> iterator = objMatch.keys();
        int counter = 0;

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = iterator.next();
            try {
                JSONObject value = objMatch.getJSONObject(key);
                Log.e("Value: ", value.toString());
                // Here you have to add values in Items_list  and then after add it in matches list
                counter++;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // Something went wrong!
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Total Records: " + counter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // After competition of iterator loop, you have to set that List in RecyclerView Adapter here
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've given here a piece of code so if there are any error correct it please

Comment: Give me few mins.

Comment: @MansurAsif Check my updated answer. You have to manage Values of Match and have to add those values in List by your self according to your requirement and Model class.

Comment: You are most welcome. You can also upvote my answer so it can be helpful for others. Happy Coding.

Comment: 1 more question please, now how can I populate these all matches in recyclerview?

Comment: You have to create an object of Items_list and fill the values in it then add that model class in your List/ArrayList. Then after you can pass that ArrayList in your RecyclerView Adapter where you have written code to display all items. I recommend using ArrayList instead of List. I have added a comment in the code as well. You can google it that how to fill values in ArrayList.

Comment: Yes. I recommend you to google how to create ArrayList and add model/POJO class values in it. Also refer RecyclerView examples to display data. You will get lots of example and tutorials. Display data is not part of this question so you have to create a new question for it.

Answer (score 2):

Toasts can only be shown on looper threads such as the main thread. My guess is the callbacks from Volley run on a worker thread.

Show your toast from the main thread:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread({
    Toast.makeText(...).show()
})
```

I'm using the Java 8 lambda notation, but you can adapt it to `Runnable`.

That being said, read all the other answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

you must use `getActivity()` or `getContext()` in Fragments to get default context and use it.
so clean `v.getContext()` and call one of above methods

Comment: @Mansur Asif    did you try log instead of toast i think toast does not work in threads and in volley onResponse Thread too, just try log instead of Toast

Comment: I'm getting json on console but not on device

Comment: ok then as i said you cannot show toast in volley OnResponse just write a method and pass your message as parameter in and after that write your toast in that method to work

Comment: @Mansur Asif did you try writing method i said above?

Comment: No brother I really didn't get what u said

Answer (score 0):

The [Toast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#summary) `makeText` method is overloaded, it can be loaded passing a resource ID

> makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)

or passing the text to show

> makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)

If you load it with an integer `live_match.length()` Android tries to load the required resource but it can't be found so the Toast is not shown. To reach your goal you must convert that integer to an String (CharSequence actually) as said in the comments.

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(live_match.length()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If this doesn't work, be sure you can touch the main thread from there, I think you are loading the Toast in a background thread where isn't allowed to touch the user interface

Comment: problem still here

Comment: @MansurAsif https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat or https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Comment: @MansurAsif Are you sure you can touch the UI from there? Are you in the correct thread?

Comment: I'm not showing any UI here I just have recyclerview where i've modify it but not response from that

Comment: By showing the Toast you are touching the UI, check the @eugen-pechanec answer